# Error when debugging Android application with ant

Tags: android

it gives me an error when i try to debug android app with ant
the error is:

-package-debug-sign:
[apkbuilder] WARNING: Using deprecated 'basename' attribute in ApkBuilderTask.Use 'apkfilepath' (path) instead.
[apkbuilder] WARNING: Using deprecated inner element in ApkBuilderTask.Use instead.